How can I Fix the path not found compiler error when configuring in CMake (in fxsdk), specifically for c++?
I am using ubuntu (in VS) + fxsdk to compile a programme to make an add-in for the casio fx-cg50.
I cannot seem to find a way to get the CXX (- fxsdk uses sh-elf-g++ and sh-elf-gcc for CC/C and C++ Respectively) compiler that CMake will recognise. If you have used CMake before you may recognise the error I explain below and I've seen other queries ask this but not with sh-elf-g++ and fxsdk specifically, and thus the solutions also differ significantly.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
So far the programme has worked in terms of installing everything (including sh-elf-g++ ish... i'll get to that) but when I type the command fxsdk build-cg -3/fsdk build-fxg3a to configure, whilst sh-elf-gcc works (i.e the C compiler identification is outputted, etc) but the code brings an error when it gets to the CXX compiler, saying its identification is unknown:
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project): 
    The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

sh-elf-g++

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

I've confirmed that it is installed as it is in the path /usr/bin/sh-elf-g++ however upon requesting the version, this is what appears for sh-elf-gcc and sh-elf-g++ respectively:
for sh-elf-g++
sh-elf-gcc --version
output:
sh-elf-gcc (GCC 13.2.0-3ubuntu1 Debian 8ubuntu1) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
for sh-elf-g++
sh-elf-g++ --version
output:
sh-elf-g++:command not found
Perhaps i never installed it? Nevertheless, upon typing sudo apt install g++-sh-elf it's unable to locate the package, but it does install successfully for gcc.
I am unaware of how I can continue with the configuration from this point, so I will appreciate any advice.

Ubuntu does not ship a C++ compiler for this architecture, period. You will have to find another way of getting a cross compiler. Either by building it yourself or by starting from the repository set up by the fxsdk creator
